# Class Unavailable. Unwind segues are not available on iOS versions prior to 6.0

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment-target

I'm trying to use unwind segues in an existing iOS project, and ran into this error - "Class Unavailable. Unwind segues are not available on iOS versions prior to 6.0.".  I've set my deployment target to "7.1" and build SDK to "Latest iOS (iOS 7.1)".

What am I missing?  Why does xcode think I'm trying to build for < 6.0?

Comment: Is your storyboard's IB target set to something <6? Also, check your binary. Your project may be set to 7.1 but your binary might be set to something else.

Comment: Ahh yes...thank you.  My interface builder target was set to build for "iOS 5.1 and later". How do I accept your comment as an answer?  Or is this question too much of a noob question to be on stack overflow?  Thank you!

Comment: Personally I think the problem and solution are pretty interesting and I wish @JasonCoco would add his comment as an answer so we can upvote it. I find storyboard / nib targets confusing and tend to neglect them; clearly this is a case where it makes a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though IB is now integrated into Xcode, it was originally its own program and it is still its own compile step. Because of that, you can target individual storyboards and nibs with specific file formats (what version of Xcode can open these) and specific deployment targets (what version of iOS or OS X will run these).

It's always important to make sure that your storyboard or xib file is targeted to the same release as your app, unless you're dynamically loading them. In which case you may have a storyboard that gets loaded on iOS 7 and a different storyboard that gets loaded—perhaps with less features—on iOS 6 or before. Then these storyboards could be targeted to those deployment targets individually, and will warn or cause errors when certain, unavailable features are used.

I don't know for sure, but I think there are sometimes some older templates that target certain xib or storyboard files to something like iOS 6, so always check for that!

To check, select the IB document you're interested in, open the inspector window and select the file inspector (CMD+ALT+2), and check the *Interface Builder Document* section.